# React input losing focus in Datatable in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

In my Datatable the input loses focus when I type any char in the input and define the componenent inside the component. However when I put the component directly in the datatable it works. I know that the first case doesnt work because the component rerenders every time I type a character. But why does the second case work? And how can I get the first case to work without put the code directly in the datatable.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-2p30w

**Dont Work (First Case)**

```
import Datatable from "react-table";
import { useState } from "react";
const Test = () => {
  const [first, setFirst] = useState("");
  const [second, setSecond] = useState("");

  const Field1 = () => (
    <input
      defaultValue={first}
      onChange={(e) => setFirst(e.currentTarget.value)}
    />
  );

  const Field2 = () => (
    <input
      defaultValue={second}
      onChange={(e) => setSecond(e.currentTarget.value)}
    />
  );

  return (
    <Datatable
      noText
      pageSize={1}
      showPagination={false}
      data={[{ userName: "asdas", email: "asdsad" }]}
      columns={[
        {
          Header: "www",
          accessor: "userName",
          Cell: <Field1 />
        },
        {
          Header: "Email",
          accessor: "email",
          Cell: <Field2 />
        }
      ]}
    />
  );
};

export default Test;
```

**Work (Second Case)**

```
import Datatable from "react-table";
import { useState } from "react";
const Test = () => {
  const [first, setFirst] = useState("");
  const [second, setSecond] = useState("");

  return (
    <Datatable
      noText
      pageSize={1}
      showPagination={false}
      data={[{ userName: "asdas", email: "asdsad" }]}
      columns={[
        {
          Header: "www",
          accessor: "userName",
          Cell: (
            <input
              defaultValue={first}
              onChange={(e) => setFirst(e.currentTarget.value)}
            />
          )
        },
        {
          Header: "Email",
          accessor: "email",
          Cell: (
            <input
              defaultValue={second}
              onChange={(e) => setSecond(e.currentTarget.value)}
            />
          )
        }
      ]}
    />
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The focus gets lost because you declare the `Field1` and `Field2` components in the body of `Test`, which means fresh components are created on each render, and any state will be lost. You can fix it by lifting the `Field1` & `Field2` definitions to the top-level scope and replacing the local-variable references with props (which will make them equal, so you can just use a single `Field`):

```
const Field = ({ defaultValue, onChange }) => (
  <input defaultValue={defaultValue} onChange={onChange} />
);

const Test = () => {
  const [first, setFirst] = useState("");
  const [second, setSecond] = useState("");

  return (
    <Datatable
      noText
      pageSize={1}
      showPagination={false}
      data={[{ userName: "asdas", email: "asdsad" }]}
      columns={[
        {
          Header: "www",
          accessor: "userName",
          Cell: (
            <Field
              defaultValue={first}
              onChange={(e) => setFirst(e.currentTarget.value)}
            />
          )
        },
        {
          Header: "Email",
          accessor: "email",
          Cell: (
            <Field
              defaultValue={second}
              onChange={(e) => setSecond(e.currentTarget.value)}
            />
          )
        }
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-forked-ij6yp?file=/src/DontWork.js:72-955)